# Do we dress for other people or ourselves?

Tags: psychology, aesthetics

This leads to a larger question about ego and ambition, but to keep it simple...

A lot of people dress to look good in front of people, so they choose items they think will look good. Other people don't necessarily think those items look that good though, so why bother? Aren't the chances much the same if you just chose something random within the scope of TRENDS?

TRENDS... are seemingly the result of common (perhaps unconscious in some) agreement on a currently desired look. However, within these trends people still tend to be picky. Why? It can't be because they dress for others, given that the chances of impressing aren't known, and you might as well just pick something random. Why try to be known as that guy that looks cool with the watch? After all, that's just what YOU would think if you saw someone wearing it. Does it mean there's no point?

Or maybe, they dress to please themselves. To impress themselves. Confusingly, I find most people are more impressed with themselves when they realize they're impressing others.

See my problem here?

Comment: As phrased, this seems more like a psychology question than a philosophy question. Can you rework it a bit to make the philosophical problem more obvious?

Comment: I feel like matthewatabet went in the direction I wanted. He put it more philosophically. The main point is that, inevitably, after taking psychology into account,  you get to the point where you need to ask: Is fashion a form of symbolism? If so, do fashion signs apply to just my subjective viewpoint, or are they interpreted by others a similar way, like a connotation. It's my belief that the more subtle the fashionable choice, the more variance there is in the interpreted connotation. But someone that stands out a lot will be easier to relate to a specific group of people, or genre.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, it just seems like the average person need not bother being picky as long as it's providing a reasonable amount of connotative difference. After checking off the connotative effects, they might as well close their eyes and just pick random items, like abstract art. I'm very much questioning the practicality of semiotic choices in relation to fashion that falls within a given trend or sub-trend. "You already give the impression of a CEO, so why that particular pair of shoes?" Sure, you liked them, but it doesn't make a difference unless you dress for yourself.

Comment: It becomes circular, because to dress for yourself is to convey what you want. To convey what you want is to try to dress for others... It's confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a number of perspectives on this question. Here is just one:

From a semiotics standpoint, fashion (like language) is *coded* and refers to other, pre-existing codes. Each fashion choice (whether conscious or not) carries a connotation (it's meaning in reference to the larger domain) in addition to a denotation (it's uniquely identifying features and functional intent). While connotation and denotation are commonly applied to spoken language, the ideas apply equally to fashion (or any other system of signs). For example, a pair of jeans has the denotation of 'riveted clothing covering the legs' along with many complex connotations such as "cowboy," "rebel," "iconoclast, "count-culture member," etc.

People sometimes wear clothes to impress others, but that is only one use of the coded system of fashion. Fashion may also be used to blend into the crowd, express power, set oneself apart from the herd, demonstrate membership in a social class, etc.

Like all languages, fashion does depend upon mutual agreement about the meaning of codes amongst the groups communicating. At the same time, fashion (and language) is always evolving and users of the code may break established codes in order to challenge norms. Thus, trends emerge to help communicate ideas previously inexpressible. For example, start-up CEOs may wear Crocs, hoodies, and jeans to challenge convention ideas of executives (a group often referred to as "suits"). Or, long facial hair may again become popular, alluding to the previous "robber barons" as an expression of power.

According to this view, we do dress for ourselves in the sense that we use fashion to achieve some subjective intention. At the same time, we dress for others because the nature of the language of fashion is social and depends upon mutual agreement (even when we break norms) for its connotative power.

See Roland Barthe's The Fashion System for a more detailed discussion.
Daniel Chandler's Semiotics for Beginner's is also very helpful:
http://visual-memory.co.uk/daniel/Documents/S4B/semiotic.html

Comment: Very interesting answer! I wrote some of my thoughts as comments on the question itself above.

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's inherently both for others, and ourselves. It's strange.

Comment: @thelittlegumnut thanks -- I'm happy you enjoyed the answer. If it was helpful, would you mind up-voting it? Whether intentional or not, the CEO who dresses "below" their station is indeed challenging the existing code and influencing it. Over time, this deviance may become "transparent" -- accepted as part of the norm.

Comment: I would up-vote if I could, but I just don't have enough reputation yet. I accepted your answer though.